# Check status of scanner in delphi througn MCMTwain

Tags: delphi

I am using delphi and MCMTwain for scanning.When i click scan button and if the scanner is of the application goes stuck.I need to check whether the scanner is online or offline before scanning .How can i check this criteria in MCMtwain

Comment: Did you check the [FAQ](http://www.mcm-design.com/index.php?section=faq) of the vendor? "If you cannot find the answer to you question in the list below - then forward your question to"

Answer (score 0):

Here is some old code that I have but cannot run anymore.
It should demonstrate a possible workflow and hopefully helps you solve your issue.

```
var
  Twain: TDelphiTwain;
  SelectedSource: Integer;

begin
  Twain.LoadLibrary;
  Twain.LoadSourceManager;

  SelectedSource := Twain.SelectSource;
  if SelectedSource <> -1 then
  begin
    Twain.Source[SelectedSource].LoadSource;

    { set TransferMode }
    Twain.Source[SelectedSource].TransferMode := ttmNative;

    Twain.Source[SelectedSource].EnableSource(True, True);

    { I am not sure if ProcessMessages is necessary here }
    while Twain.Source[SelectedSource].Enabled do
      Application.ProcessMessages;  
  end;

  Twain.UnloadLibrary;
end;
```

When the acquisition is done, the `OnTWAINImageReady` event of the `TDelphiTwain` component is being fired and there you can handle the acquired image.